# Why is my texture not appearing?

Tags: texturing

[image]

I'm having a problem with the FBX I downloaded from Sketchfab. I can't seem to see the textures though they align perfectly. I'm new to blender.[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show your Shader Editor? Maybe you need to plug some Image Texture nodes into the Principled BSDF

Comment: I have just added my Shader Editor. I believe everything is well connected.

Comment: you need to plug the top Image Texture into the Base Color input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: maybe pack the images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see at least 3 reasons.

1. File name in texture editor is different from in shader (nodes) editor.
2. You plug in texture in **subsurface** instead of **base color**
3. You get alpha channel (gray dot) from texture.